# Why does sl have different speed in different environments?

Tags: linux, macos, unix, speed

Perhaps this may seem a silly question, because the utility `sl` is a rightful member of each page containing the words **`Linux`** and **`fun`**. I was wondering why does `sl` on my **Debian** in `ssh` session work two times(`6 secs` vs `12 secs`) slower than on my **Darwin**.

[image: sl]

I use **xterm-256color** on **Debian** and **xterm-256color** inside **iTerm** on **OS X**. Also tested with **Terminal** (`11 secs`) and **x11 xterm** (`16 secs`). `ssh $USER@localhost` gives no difference.

Is there an explainable reason for such a phenomenon? Perhaps it's just a couple of keywords, but I have no clue to them. `sl` is the most remarkable program with the actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your Linux: on my system

```
  $ time sl

    real    0m4.357s
    user    0m0.023s
    sys     0m0.018s
  $ uname -a
      Linux rasal 3.13.0-58-generic #97-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 8 02:56:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

EDIT:

I presume the difference lies in the power of the processor, not on the quality of the OS:

```
  # lshw | grep i7
      product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3520M CPU @ 2.90GHz
      version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3520M CPU @ 2.90GHz
```

Mine is a reasonably upscale CPU, not really top of the line, but good anyway.

Comment: Is there something common among *nixes that makes it so different? Thanks for your example, by the way, I don't know how to beat your score.
I have made 4 tests with different result on one system, so it's not the main reason I suppose.

Comment: @theoden Please see my Edit

Comment: I don't know how to see if what you said is what troubles the program, because I'm running my **Debian** in **VBox** with 8GB RAM and 4 CPU. `product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4870HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz`.